# How can to access other website using iframe

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How can I auto-login or access in other website using an iframe?
I don't get cookies because of not the same domain.
on my website and I don't know what to do.

Do you have any suggestions about what to do?

thank you for helping.

Comment: Is selenium a viable option?

Comment: Hi sir i dont have idea about selenium

Comment: I cant dont no what to say but this is the example
mywebsite.com.ph then i want to access or autologin facebook.com.ph

Comment: This is how www is designed to keep people from stealing each other's session. Do you own both websites? Update your question with details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate via third-party apps like google or facebook?

Comment: @AlfredoZamudio yes sir.